# How to share only jpeg images with scheme "content" with my app?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

To achieve the sharing with my app I have added intent filter like this

```
<intent-filter>
            <data android:mimeType="image/jpeg" android:scheme="content"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

but it doesn't show my app when I want to share the photo. But if I remove this `android:scheme="content"` it works.

Comment: It works? What do you mean? If it works then what is the problem?

Comment: I mean I see my app when going to share a photo, but not filtered by scheme content. I need that filter, but with with scheme filter my app is not in the shareable apps when I'm going to share.